# Animation Nodes not rendering in cycles with Text Transform Blender 2.9

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a counter animation in addition to a scaling animation, while my counter animation is updating in the render in cycles, my scaling animation which is working in the viewport is not updating at all and I have no idea why, I tried to set to keyframe but it is still not working. I am using blender 2.9 the latest version.

Please help, Thanks in advance

Here is a screenshot of my node tree :

[image: Animation Node Tree]

Comment: The screenshot is hard to read (too low resolution). Please consider posting another one and/or share your blend file. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I found a workaround by just keyframing the scaling manually, why I didn't do that first is because when I tried it first it ended up not working, I don't understand what changed before and now but I find a solution thanks!